# ADFS vNext Client Authentication (WPF) (Windows Server 2016 Preview 3)

Tags: wpf, powershell, authentication, oauth, adfs

I have a Windows Server 2016 TechnicalPreview 3 with a configured ADFS vNext, as first client I have created an MVC Application as a ReplingPartyTrust. 
The authentication with the ADFS work really well with the MVC Application.
Now to the problem: I have written a Native Application (WPF) which i want to authenticate against the ADFS. 
The Steps i did are:

1. To inform the ADFS of my new WPF Client i ran the the following PowerShell Script:

   Add-ADFSClient -ClientType Public -Name “MyClient” -ClientId “E1CF1107-FF90-4228-93BF-26052DD2C714” -RedirectUri “https://E1CF1107-FF90-4228-93BF-26052DD2C714/redir´”
2. To authenticate the client (Code-Wise) i used the following NuGet-Package:
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (3.5 (Alpha))
   Then I wrote the following code:

```cs
string authority = "https://win2016preview.server.local/adfs/ls";
string resourceURI = "https://adfs.server.local/MyMVCApp";
string clientReturnURI = "https://e1cf1107-ff90-4228-93bf-26052dd2c714/redir";
string clientID = "E1CF1107-FF90-4228-93BF-26052DD2C714";
var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientID, new 
Uri(clientReturnURI), 
new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, new  
WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle));
```

With this code, the client should authenticate at the ADFS (over OAuth i think) and prompt the user to enter his organisation credentials.
If i run the application this window appears:

I choose Yes (Ja) and the credential prompt opens. In the same time the following exception occures

In the event log if the server ADFS the following error message appears:

> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthAuthorizationUnauthorizedClientException: MSIS9321: Received invalid OAuth request. The client 'E1CF1107-FF90-4228-93BF-26052DD2C714' is forbidden to access the resource 'https://adfs.server.local/MyMVCApp.
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthAuthorization.OAuthAuthorizationRequestContext.ValidateCore()
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.ProtocolContext.Validate()
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthAuthorization.OAuthAuthorizationProtocolHandler.GetRequiredPipelineBehaviors(ProtocolContext pContext)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GatherDeviceSecurityToken(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

As far as i can tell, the ADFS recognizes the Client Id and tries to authenticate it. But the ADFS rejects the Client.
Did i forget to configure something? The client should just prompt the user, which authenticates against the ADFS, so the client can habe the AuthenticationToken.

I hope you can follow me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple :)

Add the property IssuanceAuthorizationRules (Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust )

-IssuanceAuthorizationRules '=> issue (Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit" value = "true");'

Comment: When I try the above, I get the following on powershell "PS0238: Should not configure authorization or authentication rules together with an access control policy"

Comment: So you have to powershell and remove "Access Control Policy" from this RPT, and then only try this command

Comment: After that, im still getting the same error MSIS9321

Comment: Using ADFS on Windows 2016 RTM, this no longer works.  I've reproduced this exact code here, and tried both the default access rights (Permit Everyone) and the rights specified here using *-IssuanceAuthorizationRules* and with both I continue to get the *"MSIS9321: Received invalid OAuth request. The client  is forbidden to access the resource"* error.